# More performant to filter array or set and then convert to array? (Swift)

Tags: swift

I have a list of around 1000 objects containing several properties. My UI needs them ordered and I can filter them.

I understand that sets are much more performant, so my question is, is it better to just use the array and filter on it or to internally keep a set, perform all filtering on it, and then always convert it back to an array before returning it to the UI?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what an object you're talking about exactly is?

Comment: Sets are not much more performant. Sets impose overhead on every insertion that may be worthwhile if membership tests are common on a large collection (how large "large" is depends on many factors, and can be as small as a handful up to hundreds or thousands before breaking even). Depending on your specific situation, arrays or sets may be faster. As a rule, arrays will always be faster if you're just inserting a bunch of items and then iterating over all of them, because then you don't get any of the benefits of sets but you pay the cost.

Comment: Start with the meaning of the data. Is it "an unordered collection of unique items?" If so, then a Set may be appropriate. Is it an ordered collection (which sounds like your case)? Then an Array is the obvious choice. If you are uncertain which to choose, my personal advice is to use Array because it is the simplest to work with. (Some disagree with me, and say you should always use Set unless order explicitly matters. It's a reasonable debate, but I still strongly favor Array.) But you should definitely not use one or the other because you believe it is "more performant" in a general way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just 1000 objects it shouldn't really matter.

You may try the following test (for 1 million objects):

```
struct Foo: Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

let fooArr: [Foo] = (1...1_000_000).map { Foo(id: $0, name: "hkafghhkjdsgfajhkgfkjhasdf") }
let fooSet: Set<Foo> = Set(fooArr)

let start1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let filteredArr = fooArr.filter { $0.id.isMultiple(of: 2) }
let diff1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start1
print("Array: \(diff1) seconds")
// prints "Array: 4.004199028015137 seconds"

let start2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let filteredSetToArr = Array(fooSet.filter { $0.id.isMultiple(of: 2) })
let diff2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start2
print("Set: \(diff2) seconds")
// prints "Set: 4.139569997787476 seconds"
```

Again there isn't much of a difference. The actual values may differ but the relative difference should be similar for every try.

I used `-Ofast` optimisation level.

---

You can even make more detailed tests:

```
let fooArr: [Foo] = (1...1_000_000).map { Foo(id: $0, name: "hkafghhkjdsgfajhkgfkjhasdf") }
let fooSet: Set<Foo> = Set(fooArr)

let start1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let filteredArr = fooArr.filter { $0.id.isMultiple(of: 2) }
let diff1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start1
print("Array filtering: \(diff1) seconds")

let start2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let filteredSet = Array(fooSet.filter { $0.id.isMultiple(of: 2) })
let diff2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start2
print("Set filtering: \(diff2) seconds")

let start3 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let filteredSetToArr = Array(filteredSet)
let diff3 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start3
print("Set to Array: \(diff3) seconds")

print("Set total: \(diff2 + diff3) seconds")
```

and the result will be:

```
Array filtering: 1.5497009754180908 seconds
Set filtering: 1.2836240530014038 seconds
Set to Array: 1.895427703857422e-05 seconds
Set total: 1.2836430072784424 seconds
```

Note that filtering is way more expensive than conversion from Set to Array.

Comment: Just remember to benchmark using release `-O (optimize for speed)` Swift compiler setting

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks a lot. The calculations are way faster now (the relative difference is still the same).

Comment: `$0.id.isMultiple(of: 2)` Btw There is no need to initialize a new array. Just map the range `(1...1_000_000).map`